# How to add a description to an image field?

Tags: entities, media

I have a content type which has a **field** of the **image field** type.

When editing this field I see that I can:

```
Enable Alt field
```

and also can:

```
Enable Title field
```

Is there any way to **Add a Description field** to be shown under each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One other option to consider and may not work for you is to use the EXIF module and have it automatically grab the EXIF caption and then you are good to go with bulk upload using something like: [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) You then simply add in an EXIF field that grabs the image data and run drush exif-update but I am not sure if this fits your use case, it's purely dependent on the images having embedded EXIF data (i.e. from Adobe Lightroom or iPhoto).

It's primarily how I built my new site, High Rock Photo but only with single images in my case but I think it would be extendible with the Multiupload Imagefield Widget. Just thought I would throw it out there.

Here is my recipe:

- [Title Module](http://drupal.org/project/title) (converts the traditional Title to a field so you can do stuff with it).
- Token
- [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle/)
- [Exif](http://drupal.org/project/exif)
- You would add Multiupload Imagefield Widget as mentioned above. I have used this module but not within this exact recipe.

Essentially what I did was use The Title module and replace the traditional title so you can then set it to not required. Use Auto Nodetitles to grab a token from Exif data from the image and use it as an automatic title. Note you can really use Exif data for any field to display so you may not even need to do the whole replace Title nonsense. If I have some time I will run a test with this using the Multi upload widget. For my image description, I use the Exif `iptc_caption` from my image.

Note [there is a bug](http://drupal.org/node/1606294) (not fixed yet or responded to by maintainer) for Exif that makes you run drush exif-update every time you resave a node. Not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

To do that you'd need to add another column to the field type, which there's no native support for currently.

You're not alone in wanting this functionality (I'd definitely like it) and there is a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/691932#comment-5371474) that adds a `hook_field_schema_alter()` function to the field module, which you can use to add extra columns. I haven't tried it but the comments and tests on the above link seem to suggest it does work.

Bear in mind if you go down that route you'll also have to implement a few other alter hooks (`hook_field_widget_form_alter()` for example) so it's not a quick-fix.

If you're not up for patching core you might just want to use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to accomplish something similar. You can add a collection item containing an image widget and textarea widget to basically achieve the same effect (although there is some very slight impact on performance).

Comment: Yeah, the Field Collection option works.  I have never really noticed a performance impact.  Working with them can be a bit of a pain, though.  Reworking the markup can be a little rough, too.

Comment: I also thought of Field Collection, but I need to upload 100 images. I can do it at once with image field and the multiupload_imagefield_widget module. If I use Field collection I need to upload every image manually.

Comment: Hmm, looks like patching the field module is the only way you'll be able to do that

Comment: +1 for Field Collection, I think it would work great for this.

Comment: I see, I'll try to find other way to do it.

Comment: @DannyEnglander: it is good idea but the problem is that I need to bulk upload the images.

Comment: @chefnelone - one other option to consider and may not work for you is to use the EXIF module and have it automatically grab the EXIF caption and then you are good to go with bulk upload using something like: http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget You then simply add in an EXIF field that grabs the image data and run `drush exif-update` but I am not sure if this fits your use case, it's purly dependent on the images having embedded EXIF data (i.e. from Adobe Lightroom or iPhoto). It's primarily how I built my new site, High Rock Photo. Just thought I would throw it out there.

Comment: @Danny That's a good suggestion you should put it in as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This issue inspired me to build the [Image Field Caption](http://drupal.org/project/image_field_caption) module for Drupal 7.

The module adds an extra text area, similar to the alt/title text fields, for image fields. The caption text area can be used to add plain text or an html description to an image field.

1. Download the module
2. Enable the module
3. Add a content type with an image field, or use an existing content type with an image field
4. Add or edit a node with an image field
5. Enter text or html into the image field caption text area
6. Save the node and view it to see the caption displayed below the image field

To customize the caption display, take a copy of the image_field_caption.tpl.php file and place it in your theme's directory, for example:

```
sites/all/themes/MY_THEME/image_field_caption.tpl.php
```

Now you can modify the html to meet your needs.

Comment: After enabling this module, the caption text area doesn't show up. I've cleared the cache. I'm trying to add the caption to an existing image field in an existing content type with existing content.

Comment: Update: Just noticed it only doesn't work when using the Media Browser widget type for image.

Comment: @Randell please notify the issue queue here: https://drupal.org/project/issues/image_field_caption

Answer (score 1):

Also For adding caption to image there is some module

[Image Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption)

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> This module uses JQuery to dynamically add captions to images. The
>   image title attribute is used to create the caption. It basically
>   wraps the image in an html container div, takes the image title text
>   and appends that in a child div underneath the image. Technically, it
>   works by implementing Drupal's hook_nodeapi to add one small snippet
>   of captioner jquery to the head section of the page when a node of the
>   configured type is viewed.

[Image Field Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption)

> Description: Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.
>
> Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image
>   field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html
>   descriptions of an image.

[JCaption](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcaption)

> Description: This is a simple module for Drupal 7.x that uses jQuery
>   to transform the TITLE or ALT attribute of a image to a image caption.
>   There is a settings page with lot's of possible configuration. The
>   image caption won't show in the WYSIWYG-editor, but will be visible
>   when you view the node.
>
> The module differs in several ways from similar modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the title field as description, you can use the [Image Caption](http://drupal.org/project/image_caption) or [Image Caption Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/image_caption_formatter)module. There is a [request](http://drupal.org/node/1336926) to get something like this included in core for D8. It would be based on the html5 caption tag.